# What exactly is a no-parameter method name?

Tags: iphone, core-data

From the Core Data docs:

> A property name cannot be the same as
>   any no-parameter method name of
>   NSObject or NSManagedObject—for
>   example, you cannot give a property
>   the name “description”

Ok, so -description is blocked for property names. I guess it's because of KVC. But what exactly does "no-parameter" mean? Is that any method which does not take a parameter?

So in other words:

- Any property of NSObject or NSManagedObject
- ANY method name of NSObject or NSManagedObject, which does not take a parameter

Did I get that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any unary message is a no parameter method name. I.e., -copy, -retain, -release, are all unary messages when sent, and no parameter methods when you define them. An example of a keyword message (or a method with parameters) is: +stringWithString:, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, you probably mean +stringWithString: